# PHP while() fails to stop looping

Tags: php

I was getting a problem because using while() function but I'm solving it for five or six hours today. I'm asking here because I don't understand how it could be.
Here is my code

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT saldo from stock where id >= '$id' and idItem = '$idItem';")
```

if I try :

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
while($row)
{   // my code is here
}
```

then, while() fails to stop looping. but if I try like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{//my code is here 
}
```

by that code, I'm getting the correct result.

I feel this is little strength because I think the first and the second code have same function.
thanks for you comments or answers!

Comment: Your first example loops indefinitely because you are testing the same value each time. Your second example changes the value at each iteration.

Comment: "I feel this is little strength because I think the first and the second code have same function." : The first and second lines don't have the same function. At all. If you are fetching exactly one row though, then you shouldn't be using a loop.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_array()` fetches one row at once when you use in while it fetch next row every time. It returns true if there is any next row to fetch and false if there is not.

For preventing infinite loop, Use this is correct syntax for fetching:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{   
    //your code
}
```

> **Note:** The [original MySQL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead,
>   use the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extensions

Answer (score 0):

`$row` is not affected by the loop, so of course it keeps looping.  You probably want something like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{   // processing code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first snippet, the loop condition is always `true` because the value of `$row` never changes and you're ending up in an infinite loop.

In the second snippet, `$row` is re-assigned upon each loop iteration and once it's `null` (usually at the end of the recordset in the case of `mysql_fetch_array`) the loop terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Because first code uses same $row every time, the loop never stops and it doesn't even fetch the result per each iteration.
But the second code fetches result every time, the loop works as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the second one eventually stops, is because every call to `mysql_fetch_array()` will call the next row from your database query. Once all the rows have been called, it will start returning false and this is what ends the loop.

It can be a little confusing because you're not seeing any counter, but the counter is really hidden inside the `mysql_fetch_array()` function, and will eventually terminate.

But if you put that call outside the while loop, it's only called once and you keep iterating the same row.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
   while($row)
    {   // my code is here
    }
```

mysql_fetch_array fetches  1 and only 1 row from your table into $row, so if you have one row matching your query you dont need a while

if the resulting query has more than 1 row you need to make a while to the mysql_fetch_array like this:

```
     while($row=myql_fetch_array($sql){}
```

now you can get all the rows from your table

Answer (score 0):

The value of `$row` is not changed in the first case. You would need to update it again within the loop with another assignment, so your 2nd statement is better, as it does it all in one go :)

Answer (score 0):

For -

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
while($row)
{   // my code is here
}
```

`$row` is always true as it contains the values so the loop will be executed infinitely. And

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{//my code is here 
}
```

`$row` is ture untill the `mysql_fetch_arrya` has values.

`mysql` is deprecated. Try to use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score -4):

Try this code:

You have a semicolon inside your query.. your semicolon must be at the end of the mysql_query() function. That may be the cause of your infinite looping in while loop.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT saldo FROM stock WHERE id >= '$id' AND idItem = '$idItem'");
```

Comment: Completely wide of the mark. See my comment above, or any of the other answers.

Comment: Semicolons are a valid part of SQL syntax. Since `mysql_query` only allows single SQL statements, they are optional (and specifically recommended against), but still valid.